# Extract data from PDF document to CSV

Tags: pdf, csv, file-conversion, parsing

I would like to convert a stack of financial documents, identically formated, into a CSV file.

Here is an example:

[image: Example]

I have a program to do the OCR (optical character recognition) so that is not the major concern. What I need help with is parsing the PDF document into a CSV.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What PDF tools do you have? Adobe Acrobat will convert the OCR'd file or section of file to .txt or excel which is easy to convert to a .cvs file.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the attempted solution. Can the solution be used for 100+ pages or is this a manual solution?